# Backup - Is this the right place?

Tags: vmware-esx

Running Backup Exec 12.5 on separate server, running an array on a separate server for D2D storage, Running These sh###y EMC server clusters with ESX version?? running Virtual Center 2.5 Build 147633.

Their guide speaks to backup exec, but is not all inclusive. I even shelled out thousands for the class and the backup was a mere gloss over. Even when I asked specific questions pertaining to it, I was brushed off being told that he doesn't know. The only thing I did walk away with was the perception that in addition to our VMWare server, and our vmware server that 2 other servers were needed: a proxy server and a VCB server.

Can someone help me sort this crap out please. We currently have 6 server running in VMWare and no backups of the VMWare server, I am running agents on those servers and running backups on the servers themselves, but to me this is a poor solution. I would much rather have backups of the virtual devices themselves and run a secondary backup only on data. Due to the difficulty I've had with just this one issue (as well as the poor service for the astronomical costs associated with the software and the service plan), I can definitely say that I am VERY sorry that I chose VMWare as a solution over Hypervisor. But now I'm stuck and have to make this work, so can anyone help me?

-Scott

Comment: Who is 'their' guide, Symantec or EMC or vmware? What was the topic of the class? If you are dissatisfied, pursue a refund, your probably won't get one but you might at least get a free class in your desired topic.

Comment: If you took the vmware install/configure/manage class I concur.  I was shocked to learn that backups weren't part of that class (other than being peripherally discussed)-supposedly backups are part of another 5 day class, but I never bothered to find out which one

Answer (score 2):

VCB is a backup proxy - it provides you with the ability to mount the VM file structures in folders on a Windows Server. The VCB server can be a VM but performance will generally be better if it is a physical machine with a direct connection to your SAN and visibility to the shared LUNS.

The [Virtual Machine Backup Guide](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vi3_35/esx_3/r35u2/vi3_35_25_u2_vm_backup.pdf) has quite comprehensive instructions on setting this up. I wouldn't say it is simple but it is not terribly complex and you can certainly get both full VM backups of all VM Guests and File level LAN free backups (ie directly over the SAN and offloading from the Guest OS's) for Windows Systems.

There's a nice short guide on the basic steps involved on the [VMPros.nl web site](http://blog.vmpros.nl/2009/04/21/vmware-10-steps-to-install-vcb-v15/) that covers the main steps needed to get it working.

Once you are this far you can write your own scripts (using whatever scripting language you prefer and VCBmounter) to mount the relevant VM files and then just backup the data directly from the VCB server. This is going to be quite painful to manage but it is a cheap way of getting full VM\LAN free backups working.

If you want to use the BE 12.5 management interface and have it understand that it is backing up ESX Hosts\Virtual Infrastructure machines then you will have to buy the Backup Exec Agent for VMware Infrastructure. Yep it costs money but it will give you a proper management GUI for the VM's and their content that can handle all backup and restore tasks within a consistent UI.

Answer (score 1):

Do you qualify for an upgrade to Backup Exec 2010.  If you have maintenance you do. It deals with VMware much more easily.  No proxy and better granular recovery.  Single pass backups and a bunch of other stuff.  Saw a presentation yesterday and it looks way better for VMware.  Worth a look if you have the upgrade for free.   Looks like some interesting dedupe options as well.

[BUExec 2010 presentation](https://www111.livemeeting.com/cc/symantec_live/view?id=E-EU-020410)

Answer (score 0):

Basically as Helvick said. To backup the VMs running on your ESX hosts with Backup Exec, you will need:

- 1 x Backup Exec CAL for each ESX Host
- 1 x VCB Proxy Server
- 1 x Backup Exec server
- Sufficient staging space to back the VMs up.

The VCM Proxy and Backup Exec server can be the same box.

Once you've got VCB and Backup Exec installed with the CALs, you just point it at the VirtualCenter or each ESX host individually, and tick the VMs you want to back up.

You may need some cals for specific VMs. Exchange, SQL and Sharepoint will all need individual server CALs before you can back them up 'properly' (with full granular restore ability).